# minted change comment character

Tags: minted, comments

I am trying to add some asm code to my document with minted.
For that I have this implementation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}

% Syntax Highlighting
\usepackage{pdfcol}
\usepackage[most, minted]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,breakable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usemintedstyle{friendly}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\scriptsize {\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}
\newcommand{\myminted}[1]{\tcbinputlisting{
colback=bg,
breakable,
listing only,
listing file={#1},
minted language=nasm,
minted options={linenos,breaklines,numbersep=2mm,xleftmargin=2mm,obeytabs,tabsize=2,autogobble},
enhanced,
overlay={%
       \begin{tcbclipinterior}
           \fill[gray!25] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=6mm]frame.north west);
       \end{tcbclipinterior}
   }
}}

\begin{document}
\myminted{mwe.asm}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I need to have numbers with a # in front of them, but minted thinks that makes them a comment. I want them to be shown as numbers as if there was no # in front of them.
You can see that if you use this asm file:

```
; This should be a comment
mov R1, 56 ; <- this should be a number
mov R2, #56 ; <- this should also be a number, but isn't
```

What do I have to do to fix that behaviour?

Comment: do none of https://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#lexers-for-assembly-languages do the right thing?

Comment: That helped, thank you very much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.